# Выводить только те записи из table_1, ID который присутствуют в table_2

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Делаю вывод из БД.

Хотелось обойтись без второго **if**, например что-то вроде:

Как это возможно сделать?

**UPD**

```
$all_countries = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `onetravel_countries` ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 0, 10");
if ($all_countries) while ($country = $all_countries->fetch_assoc()) {
     $amt = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `estate_base` WHERE `country_id` = '$country[descr]' AND `useit` <> '0'"); $amt = $amt->fetch_row();
     if ( $amt['0'] > 0 ) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Смотрите в сторону `EXISTS`: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-exists/

Comment: Мне кажется что у этого элементарного запроса должен быть дубликат на русском языке, но не могу найти. [На английском есть.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158126/select-value-from-table-only-if-exist-in-another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пусть у нас есть `table_1` с колонкой `id`, и `table_2` с колонкой `country_id`. Получим только те записи из `table_1`, для которых есть соответствующая запись в таблице `table_2`:

```
SELECT `table_1`.* FROM `table_1` JOIN `table_2` 
    ON `table_2`.`country_id` = `table_1`.`id`
```

Если во второй таблице может быть несколько записей для одной из первой, то нужно дополнить запрос так:

```
SELECT `table_1`.* FROM `table_1` JOIN `table_2` 
    ON `table_2`.`country_id` = `table_1`.`id` 
    GROUP BY `table_1`.`id`
```

Так выведутся записи из первой таблицы без дублирования.

Добавление счётчика записей во второй таблице тоже проблем не представляет:

```
SELECT `table_1`.*, COUNT(*) as `cnt` FROM `table_1` JOIN `table_2` 
    ON `table_2`.`country_id` = `table_1`.`id` 
    GROUP BY `table_1`.`id`
```

[Раздел в руководстве.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Comment: Ему вообще-то нужно количество по table_2...

Comment: в итоге вообще ничего не выводит(

Comment: @iKey покажите структуру таблиц и примеры данных; без них как проверить что всё работает?..

Comment: @Akina в исходной постановке вопроса "Выводить только те записи из table_1, ID который присутствуют в table_2" про число записей ничего нет

Comment: А *SELECT **COUNT(\*)*** Вы не видите?

Comment: Вижу, и не вижу для чего это кроме того чтобы убрать отсутствующие записи, но если вы настаиваете

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(t2.*), 0) cnt, t1.id, t1.field1, t1.field2 /* , ... */
FROM table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t2.country_id = t1.id
GROUP BY t1.id /* , t1.field1, t1.field2, ... */ 
ORDER BY t1.id LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: Почему-то никак не получается интегрировать это в свой запрос. В вопросе обновил код на оригинальный свой. Можете с  учетом его привести пример?

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @iKey Ваш вопрос - целиком и полностью по MySQL. Для уточнения ответа на именно вашей структуре данных добавьте в текст вопроса DDL обеих таблиц.